# How to set up OCI to connect to Oracle from PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

On the latest Ubuntu, I have a functioning PHP 5.2.4 installation.  I want to use a remote Oracle server from PHP using OCI.

I've downloaded the *"Instant Client Package - Basic Lite"* ([Link](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/linuxsoft.html)). I've unzipped the package containing the OCI libraries to a dir but I have no idea how to tell PHP that I want to use these libraries. Predictably, I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in...

when running this code:

```
<?php 
   $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hrpw', 'someremotehost');
?>
```

I don't want to recompile PHP with Oracle support.  What's the fastest way to wire up PHP so that I can use Oracle?  Do I need any other libaries, like the Oracle client if I want to connect to a remote Oracle instance?

Comment: I am having a somewhat similar problem, but I don't know how to recompile. Do you mean run ./configure --with-oci8 and make && make-install again in the same directory? Does that involve some other changes except these three commands?

Answer (score 4):

You need the PHP extension, try the following on your Ubuntu:

```
(sudo) pecl install oci8
```

Make sure your php.ini's (there should be one for your Apache and one for cli php) contain `extension=oci8.so` afterwards. Finally, you have to restart Apache and can confirm via `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` that the extension is loaded.

**UPDATE:**

Enter something like this when it asks you for ORACLE_HOME:

> instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient

I think setting the environment variable would be another solution. /opt/oracle... is the path I put my instantclient in. I followed some tutorial a while ago, unfortunately I can't find it anmore.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to make sure that the $ORACLE_HOME/lib32 is in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or else add that directory to the /etc/ld.so.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I downloaded Zend Core for Oracle and that worked.
http://www.zend.com/en/products/core/for-oracle

Comment: Don't use zend core for oracle, use the generic version (it has oracle support). I had a support ticket because of bugs in zend core for oracle and they told me it is deprecated and no longer actively updated.